# Map column values in SQL

Tags: sql, database

I have a table named table1, with one column named col1, which takes value in range 1-9.

```
table1
col1
1
9     
7     
2     
4     
6     
1     
9     
3     
5
```

Now I want to add another column which maps values in col1 to another value given in a map.
1 -> A, 2 -> B, 3 -> C, 4 -> D, 5 -> E, 6 -> F, 7 -> G, 8 -> H, 9 -> I

I want results to look like below.

```
col1  col2 
1     A
9     I
7     G
2     B
4     D
6     F
1     A
9     I
3     C
5     E
```

My approach is to create a new table with mapping and then do a inner join.

```
CREATE TABLE map (
    col1 int,
    col2 varchar
);

INSERT INTO map
    (col1, col2)
VALUES
    (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C'),(4,'D'),(5,'E'),(6,'F'),(7,'G'),(8,'H'),(9,'I');

SELECT table1.col1, map.col2
FROM table1 INNER JOIN map ON table1.col1 = map.col1
```

Is this efficient approach, are there better methods than this?

Comment: If your values are sequential then there are likely string functions in your specific RDBMS (you haven't told us what that is) to get the character code from which you can subtract.

Comment: values may not be sequential, only for illustration i took this example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use case statement:

```
Update t 
Update new_column = 
           Case 
              WHEN col1 = 1 THEN 'A'
              WHEN col1 = 2 THEN 'B'
              WHEN col1 = 3 THEN 'C'
              WHEN col1 = 4 THEN 'D'
              WHEN col1 = 5 THEN 'E'
              WHEN col1 = 6 THEN 'F'
              WHEN col1 = 7 THEN 'G'
              WHEN col1 = 8 THEN 'H'
              WHEN col1 = 9 THEN 'I'
           END
           FROM table1 t
```

Comment: this will overwrite the existing column, what I want is to add a new column

Comment: I change the answer by considering the new column is in same table then and you want to update it. @spb

Answer (score 2):

Although creating map table can be a good idea, assume you need to fill the map table with query. Then `case` statement is useful.

```
CASE col1
    WHEN 1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'B'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'C'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'D'
    -- And so on
END
```